# Using a group-level mean as a predictor in a mixed effects model

Tags: regression, interaction, multicollinearity

I want to fit a multi-level model across $j=1,2,3,...,k$ groups that predicts $y_{ji}$ for the ith observation in the jth cluster.

$ Y_{ji} = \alpha_j + \beta_1 X_{ji} + \beta_2 \bar{X_{j.}} + \beta_{12} X_{ji}\bar{X_{j.}} + \epsilon$

The issue I have is that the predictors $X_{ji}$ and $\bar{X_{j.}}$ are directly related breaking an assumption of the regression model. [Bafumi and Gelman](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/Bafumi_Gelman_Midwest06.pdf) discussed a hierarchical approach without the intercept, but I haven't been able to find anything else.

An idea I had was to create feature that is an all-others average; i.e., the following model where $\bar{X}_{j(-i)}$ is the average of group $j$ excluding the $i^{th}$ observation.

$ Y_{ji} = \alpha_j + \beta_1 X_{ji} + \beta_2 \bar{X}_{j(-i)} + \beta_{12} X_{ji}\bar{X}_{j(-i)} + \epsilon$

Is this acceptable? I drew it from thinking about the proof that the sample mean and variance are independent, but I don't know if this simple solution side-steps the issue.

Comment: Just an update, I found a dataset to work with and the correlation between the individuals and all-else-means was quite low. The VIF on the all-else-mean predictor was essentially 1, too.